# Electron builder: how to get the update-downloaded feed url in Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, electron, electron-builder

I'm using electron builder auto update, I'm trying to get the feed url so I did:

```
AutoUpdate.getFeedURL()
```

but it's deprecated and not working anymore.

Also I tried https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater#event-update-downloaded

```
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function(
    event: any,
    releaseNotes: any,
    releaseName: any,
    releaseDate: any,
    updateUrl: any,
): void {
    console.log('update-downloaded');
});
```

Still the updateUrl is null

So how can I get the feed url for the downloaded update?